# Is it good to have all table properties in UOW class (Generic repository pattern)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working on Asp.net MVC project. I followed the [link](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) to create generic repository.

```
public class UnitOfWork : IDisposable
{

    private LeisureEntities context = new LeisureEntities();
    private IGenericInterface<cust_order> _customerOrderRepository;
    private IGenericInterface<tblCustomer> _customerMasterRepository;


    public IGenericInterface<cust_order> CustomerOrderRepository
    {
        get
        {
            return _customerOrderRepository = new GenericRepository<cust_order>(context);
        }
    }

    public IGenericInterface<tblCustomer> CustomerMasterRepository
    {
        get
        {
            return _customerMasterRepository = new GenericRepository<tblCustomer>(context);
        }
    }

    public void SaveChanges()
    {
        context.SaveChanges();
    }



    private bool disposed = false;

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                context.Dispose();
            }
        }
        this.disposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

Can I declare all the Repositories in UOW class as properties and then use this UOW in controller or service layer directly. That means I will have only two classes in DAL one Generic repository class and one UOW class with all properties of db tables.

DO I need to create separate UOW for each table.

I am using database first approach.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No!! The approach to create UOW for all entities is a very bad approach. But the idea of abstracting the data is good.

I am using a GenericRepository for all entities. This is the best way for abstracting the data. Every repository is responsible for operations on given entity.

Then I extract all my business logic in Services -> That way the business logic is separated in a class library project following the SOLID principles.

Every object has exactly what it needs. I will provide you a open source git repository to check and reuse my architecture. Take a look in a Data folder.

The only difference is that you are using a database first approach and the solution is to extend the db context with a partial class.

Take a look at this. This is made by following the best practices. It can be extended very easy.

[Mvc eshop architecture](https://github.com/siderisltd/ShopRepo)

.....................................................................................................................................................................

Yes, the architecture is a bit abstract and from first sight too complex I guess, but this solves you super many architectural issues before they happened in the future. I will paste you the simplest service / business logic / as you wanted so that you can understand more clearly what and why it's all about.

```
using Eshop.Data.Repositories;

namespace Eshop.Services.Data
{
using Contracts;
using Eshop.Data.Models;
using System.Linq;

public class CategoriesService : ICategoriesService
{
    private IRepository<Category> repo;

    public CategoriesService(IRepository<Category> repo)
    {
        this.repo = repo;
    }

    public IQueryable<Category> GetAllCategories()
    {
        var categoriesToReturn = this.repo.All().Where(x => x.IsDeleted != true);
        return categoriesToReturn;
    }

}
```

In all services you should return IQueryable and to congest your query. In your controllers you Inject the service and the web part where the controllers are did not know anything about your data. When you inject the service with dependency inversion using Ninject or AutoFak you use those methods and materialize the query result in your controller. You can see how I inject the service in the home controller. Than the best thing you can do is to use Automapper for your viewmodels and automap the properties. In this case your controllers are remaining clean and with a couple of rows code. They fulfill their duty to cach the request, get the data and pass it to the view. I hope that this is useful to you. With this approach you can easily make a great, big projects that are working fast and are easy to support and change things. Let's say that you can very easy change the database, add method in the repository or just put some other custom action in it for example if you wanna flag all data as modified when you query it by id than you will just have to go in your GenericRepository and add this flag with one row and voila :)

Comment: This is fantastic but I am  only able to understand some part of this project. I have lot of questions but not answers. why savechanges() in generic repository class, how to achieve transaction and uow. if you can paste code for one categoryservice class it will be helpfull

Comment: Because you are working trough this Generic Repository. Everything in EF is a transaction by default. Everything is happening on EF proxies of your entities. You can change for example 20 entitiy properties and when you call SaveChanges everything will pass at once. You can implement GenericService in which you can put the common functionality between the services